# Any way to stop a command from returning exit codes?

Tags: python, shell

My goal is to write a simple python script which prints a string that includes a result from a shell command line, in this case for example will be "uname". If I do

```
import os
unameCommand=(os.system("uname"))
print("This OS is {}.".format(unameCommand))
```

the result will look like

```
$ python3 /path/to/file.py
Darwin
This OS is 0
```

but what I am expecting looks something like this:

```
$ python3 /path/to/file.py
This OS is Darwin
```

There is this exit code that I assume is causing these problems and therefore, like the question suggests, any way to stop a command from returning exit codes? If not, any other way for me to achieve the expected result?

Comment: Exit code is not command output.

Comment: You cannot use `os.system` to capture the output of a command. Take a look at the documentation for the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: The exit status is part of the kernel API and so, no, there is no way to prevent that, and it's not related to your question at all.